# How to set up a Veritas Basic Grinding jig with short chisels

Tags: sharpening

## Problem

I need to regrind new bevels on some old worn-out chisels, *without*
using free-hand techniques, which I know how to do already.  After
some belabored research on grinding jigs, I purchased a [Veritas® Basic Grinding Set](http://www.leevalley.com/US/wood/page.aspx?p=32975&cat=1,43072,45938)<sup>**1**</sup> for use with my 6" grinder.
However, the chisels I have vary in length, but most/all of them are
quite short.  In actual use, during setup, I very quickly ran into a
problem in the setup, where the short chisels do not fit the jig,
without pushing it forward so far as to then throw off all of the
dimensions that are required for the jig to work.

Is this just my not knowing how to properly set up the jig? Or, is it
due to the design assumption, by Veritas, that the jig would only be
used by chisels with long shanks?

## Details

[image: Veritas Basic Grinding Set problem with short chisels 1.png]

[image: Veritas Basic Grinding Set problem with short chisels 2.png]

[image: Veritas Basic Grinding Set problem with short chisels 3.png]

[image: Veritas Basic Grinding Set problem with short chisels 4.png]

[image: Veritas Basic Grinding Set problem with short chisels 5.png]

## Solution/Options

Some solutions I'm considering are:

1. This is just my ignorance in setting up the tool. If so, what is
   the proper setup?
2. Donate/sell the short chisels, and buy longer, higher quality
   chisels that will fit the Veritas Grinding Jig. Definitely a
   viable option, as I don't see any issues with the Veritas, if this
   was by design.
3. Only return just the [Veritas® Grinding Jig](http://www.leevalley.com/US/wood/page.aspx?p=32974&cat=1,43072,45938), keeping the [Veritas® Grinder Tool Rest](http://www.leevalley.com/US/wood/page.aspx?p=32973&cat=1,43072,45938), and
   build<sup>**2**</sup> my own jig to use with the Veritas® Grinder Tool Rest, using
   suitable plywood/hardwood/aluminum/steel. Not too difficult, but I
   don't want to spend the time on that unless someone can convince
   me that it is the best option.
4. Return the entire Veritas set, guide plus jig, and research some
   other vendor's sharpening guides and jigs. Feel free to comment on
   guides you know will work with both long and short chisels plus
   plane irons, but this is *not* intended to be a tool
   recommendation.
5. Return the entire Veritas set, guide plus jig, and
   build<sup>**2**</sup> one from scratch. There are tons of videos
   and design plans out there, but, this is a last resort as it is
   just more time spent building tools to do woodworking, versus
   well, just doing woodworking.

## Update #1

[Graphus's comment](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/9650/how-to-set-up-a-veritas-basic-grinding-jig-with-short-chisels#comment19803_9650) was:

> 1st and most important is, do the problem short chisels all need to be reground or do you just want to?

Yes, and the grinder comes into play because I want to avoid manually regrinding them on diamond stones. Examining each of the chisels closely, I found that, over the years of abuse, I've honed and rehoned each of them to the point where the entire bevel needs to be reground. Basically, what should be a microbevel is actually a rather large macro bevel, on all of them.

I will also consider the possibility of using my Extra Coarse diamond whetstones to do the coarse work. But from experience, that is a lot more work than using a grinder, that is, only if I can relatively quickly set up the chisel on a/the jig.

[Graphus's comment](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/9650/how-to-set-up-a-veritas-basic-grinding-jig-with-short-chisels#comment19804_9650) was:

> Can the jig be moved inwards so that the grinding wheel comes forward, in fact just shy of kissing the rear of the slot? This strikes me as being the main setup change that could resolve most issues, but the grinder or the base of the jig could easily not allow it.

I could and did get close, but that turned out not to be viable, because the upper-left handle bumps up against the grinder housing.  I even tried moving that handle over to the right side, but it runs into the lower-right handle. See this photo:

[image: Veritas Basic Grinding Set problem with short chisels 7.png]

I also reconfirmed the problem I detailed in the [second image above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYAMC.jpg): In order to adjust the chisel's angle of attack onto the grinding wheel, such that it meets 1/2 way up the bevel as per the instructions<sup>**4**</sup>, I indeed had to push the chisel so far forward, that the conical part of the back of the chisel abuts up against the jig top plane, tilting the chisel upward even more, throwing off the invariants the jig uses in those instructions. Thus, for these short chisels, I've concluded that jig part is not really applicable.

So "but the grinder or the base of the jig could easily not allow it" is the case here.

I neglected to show the condition of the chisels in the original question, so updating this now: This isn't a great photo as it doesn't really show the bevels with any degree of resolution, but you can kind of see the "macrobevels" from the light reflection, in this photo:

[image: Veritas Basic Grinding Set problem with short chisels 6.png]

---

<sup>**1**</sup> There are many viable options, but my read of tons of
Amazon reviews led me repeatedly back to the Veritas as "the" best
here.  Of course, I have diamond whetstones of varying grits and a
honing wheel to do the final stropping.

<sup>**2**</sup>Building tools is fun, and I have no problem with that
at all, but I do want to avoid needless [Yak Shaving](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yak_shaving)<sup>**3**</sup> or
[filling holes in buckets requiring tools that require buckets that hold water](https://www.songsforteaching.com/folk/theresaholeinthebucket.php),
etc. etc.  It might have taken me just as much time to type up this SE post as it
would to have just built my own from scratch. :)

<sup>**3**</sup> Definition #2:

> A less useful activity done consciously or subconsciously to procrastinate about a larger but more useful task.

<sup>**4**</sup> Click on the "Instr" link at the bottom of the page at [Veritas® Grinder Tool Rest](http://www.leevalley.com/US/wood/page.aspx?p=32973&cat=1,43072,45938), second page in the PDF.

Comment: Hi welcome to SE and congrats on a very thorough, well-written Question. I think bottom line is you've correctly identified what the issue is. There are essentially fatal flaws in the Veritas jig that limit its usefulness. Almost all sharpening gizmos have some in-built limitations.... *commercial* jigs in particular. Rather than pen a detailed TL;DR Answer that covers almost everything right now I just wanted to check a few things since you're stuck, 1st and most important is, do the problem short chisels all *need* to be reground or do you just want to? [contd]

Comment: Can the jig be moved inwards so that the grinding wheel comes forward, in fact just shy of kissing the rear of the slot? This strikes me as being the main setup change that could resolve most issues, but the grinder or the base of the jig could easily not allow it.

Comment: @Graphus Thank you for your insightful questions. See **Update #1** that I have added to the question text.

Comment: I've not used this jig, but would it be possible to clamp a shim plate between the jig and the chisel blade to raise it parallel to tjig bed and keep it levelo relative to the wheel?

Comment: @Ashlar Yes. To do so, I could use my dial indicator on the top to ensure parallelism, and move the shim(s) around until parallel. But, I reason that I would have to redo that same procedure for each chisel that have different levels of non-parallelism, requiring different number of shims and requisite per-chisel fiddling.  Not impossible, but well, then if the jig isn't a "set and forget" device, then I highly question the efficacy of using the jig in the first place, and just ditch the entire "use a jig" approach at all.

Comment: @Ashlar But I have not actually measured how much non-parallelism exists across my chisels. So your point is valid for sure.

Comment: Re. the Extra Coarse and how it's a bit slow if you were trying to do this work by hand, most brand-name coarser plates don't really justify the use of that word and are more realistically in a medium range. To get a *really* coarse diamond plate (150 or below) I think you may have to go with a non-brand but I'm not up on what's available in diamond plates these days because I have no interest in this end of the market.

Comment: @Graphus The reason I became excessively fixated upon the Extra Coarse (and subsequently an Extra Extra Coarse!) diamond stones is the rather laborious task I encountered in attempting to flatten the back of the first old chisel.  That chisel is currently hot-glued to a hand-made fixture in one of the annotated images in https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1zme.jpg (the chisel on the far right) so that I could work it back and forth on the Extra Coarse stone and not leave my fingers sore. [contd]

Comment: [contd] Hind-sight being 20/20: I should just have farmed out that work, or taken Solution/Option #2 and just start with a new set of nice chisels that will last me a lifetime with not too much work on the stones, hopefully resulting in little to no need for a bench grinder and its tool rest (per your **[well-written answer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/a/9653/7479)**)

Comment: The fastest cutting stone that I've found is the coarse Norton Crystolon oil stone.  It's much (much!) faster than my DMT "extra coarse" diamond plate.  Also, it's quite cheap at $20 and stays flat pretty well.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 I made a decision a while back to standardize on diamond whetstone's.  I am going to try this one out first, but I will take your recommendation as another possibility: DMT D8XX  8-inch Dia-Sharp Continuous Diamond - Extra-Extra-Coarse https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000GLPCO2/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_wZy9CbZ84NMW7

Comment: Coarse Cystolon is often cited as one of the fastest options for hand grinding and Cyrstolons are certainly not slow, but I don't think the people who have done the comparisons have used the right diamond plates. You have to be comparing 150, 120, 100 and 80 plates. Although even coarser than 80 is available o_O But 'just' 150 is nearly unbelievably aggressive, you can take off actual millimetres of steel from a chisel edge in just minutes on one. And unlike any stone you can't get a dig and it'll never dish. Perhaps best of all they cost like **five bucks** these days!

Comment: Duly noted. Since I've already purchased it prior to asking this question, going to continue with my plan to try the Extra-Extra Coarse DMT (still waiting for it to arrive). But, that may not be really be needed now that, in [my other comment](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/9650/how-to-set-up-a-veritas-basic-grinding-jig-with-short-chisels?noredirect=1#comment19833_9653), I've pretty much decided to ditch these chisels and spend my time/energy on nicer chisels. Oh well, live and learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My initial main suggestions were going to be one of the following:

- move the stand closer to the grinder, so that the wheel more fully engages with the slot created for it (**note:** the wheel being very close to the edge of any tool rest is considered important for safety)
- insert a packing piece/shim to raise the chisel, allowing the handle end to clear of the rear edge of the rest.

Since the first (the more desirable option) turns out to be impossible for you my immediate thought was to do the opposite, taking advantage of the rest's ability to tilt in either direction. Many pictures of the Veritas Grinder Tool Rest are of it angled in this direction, although just now I could only find this small one on Highland Woodworking illustrating it set up with a grinder to show this most clearly:

[image: Veritas grinder rest, set back]

Your last picture in the original post I think shows you have enough bench real estate to do this.

I can't quite tell from the photos whether this will do enough for you now, but I think it might. Now because of the depth of the 'bed' of the rest this isn't a permanent solution since as your chisels get shorter the problem area will get closer and closer to the cutting edge. However for most people this kind of wear takes years (literally decades in the majority of cases) so while not permanent it shouldn't be considered a short-term fix by any means.

Re. a real or perceived need to grind here's a progression of observations/realisations:

- Bevels don't need to be pretty for the chisel to work.
- Bevels don't need to match across a set of chisels<sup>1</sup>.
- A shallower primary bevel AKA primary grind angle is largely a convenience for fast honing, it's not mainly for chisel performance.
- Hollow grinding isn't the norm everywhere so clearly it isn't a must-do.
- Bevels don't need to be at any fixed angle. A few degrees out either positive or negative has basically no effect [This is a key observation in relation to your worry about chisels being tapered in thickness and how this throws off the grinding angle.]
- If using a primary/secondary bevel sharpening routine, the primary bevel largely doesn't do any work. The cutting edge is responsible for >95% of the way a chisel performs, 100% in the case of paring — two similar chisels, one with a 20° grind and another with a 30° grind will pare *exactly* the same if both are honed at the same angle<sup>2</sup>.
- Some woodworkers don't own a grinder and don't feel they're lacking something important by not having one<sup>3</sup>.

Some very related reading from previous Q&As here that may be of help:
[Is there a 'best' way to sharpen an edged tool like a chisel?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/672/is-there-a-best-way-to-sharpen-an-edged-tool-like-a-chisel)
[How does one aggressively sharpen chisels and plane irons when damaged?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2398/how-does-one-aggressively-sharpen-chisels-and-plane-irons-when-damaged/2401#2401)
[What criteria would want me to bevel my chisel in a certain way](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2076/what-criteria-would-want-me-to-bevel-my-chisel-in-a-certain-way/2079#2079)
[Bench grinder, tool sharpener or sharpening stone?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3670/bench-grinder-tool-sharpener-or-sharpening-stone/3701#3701)
[What's a quick, easy home-made honing guide?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/6708/whats-a-quick-easy-home-made-honing-guide/6712#6712)

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact there are some good reasons to deliberately sharpen individual chisels in a set slightly differently, the most clear being for narrower chisels (1/4" / 6mm and under especially) to be sharpened to a steeper angle to help with edge retention — because the concentration of force from a mallet blow is so much greater across a narrower cutting edge.

<sup>2</sup> The major difference in practice is said to be the speed at which you can hone them. But if your sharpening media isn't particularly slow this difference can be basically irrelevant, it's not even noticeable in some cases. In particular if you hone on diamonds. But even on oilstones (the least aggressive of the common honing surfaces and traditionally thought of as slow) I genuinely struggle to notice a difference although I'm not using any exotic alloys like A2.

<sup>3</sup> I largely subscribe to this idea, for normal day-to-day use and related sharpening of tools a grinder is not a necessity and may never be missed until an edge is chipped accidentally (obviously a rare occurrence for most).

Comment: "for normal day-to-day use and related sharpening of tools a grinder is not a necessity and may never be missed until an edge is chipped accidentally (obviously a rare occurrence for most)." really needs to be **the answer** for me as well. I'm going to return the Veritas tool rest and jig, and spend more time reading of the highlighted answers. Midway through, I discovered [your answers](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/users/243/graphus) indirectly through the [sharpening tag](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharpening). Thank you for your stupendous help!!

Comment: You're more than welcome. I wish this were a more conventional forum format so it would be easier to give you more help on this because I've been in your exact position previously, repairing and recovering older chisels in various conditions and I wasted loads of time doing things that weren't strictly necessary, a trap nearly all fall into early on. Pretty bevels and very flat, polished backs are nice, but if the goal is just to make them work properly then literally hours of work can be avoided. [contd]

Comment: To avoid wasted time on work that isn't needed the main thing is not to spend ages on the backs of chisels (ditto plane irons). The vast majority of chisels are flat enough that the back doesn't need work (*any* work) as only the strip at the edge is doing anything during the cut. So the no. 1 tip here is just to abrade that last 1/2" or so, but aiming for only a very narrow strip (~1/16") to end up honed and polished. The amount of time this saves can be staggering. Couple that with the idea that only the honed part of the bevel is important and you're looking at <10 mins instead of hours.

Comment: I assume that "So the no. 1 tip here is just to abrade that last 1/2" or so" means the bevel side, not the back, correct? If so, then that is the issue with the current chisel (the one hot-glued to the home-made holder) whereby there is a bevel (how much so? I haven't measured) that will throw off paring action. But it has been turning out to be such a huge amount of manual labor, on the Extra Coarse DMT (my Extra Extra Coarse DMT has not yet arrived). [contd]

Comment: [contd] So, so far, I'm concluding that I need to just donate/trash this awful chisel and buy longer high-quality chisels, and also take your advice and either not flatten the machined back or only do just the bare minimum on the Fine DMT stone before proceeding (https://youtu.be/f0REOnjdlQU?t=1190).

Comment: Please let me know how you find the XXCoarse DMT. It's supposed to be 120 micron which I think equates to about 150 grit but from user comments on other DMTs I suspect it's going to seem like it's finer than that. Now re. the chisel with the back bevel, even a small one is a bear to remove by lapping the back! But you have a grinder, so if you choose to return it to normal grind back until the errant bevel is gone, then reform the primary on the right side. **Or**, alternatively you could leave it this way, double-bevel chisels are useful for some tasks (Brian Boggs has one as a peg parer).

Comment: And yeah, Marc there is totally off base about lapping 2" of the back of a chisel. I have chisels where literally only 6mm or 1/4" is fully flat (behind this merely flattish *or even slightly crowned* is completely OK). And guess what? They work just fine. No matter the skills of the modern WW guru telling us to flatten big swathes of the backs of chisels and irons, the historical record is more to be trusted. Old guides say nothing about this and vintage chisels in original condition are virtually never found with much work done to their backs, 99% were flat enough as-is to work as needed.

Comment: (to the others, "Marc there" is referring to Marc Spagnuolo in https://youtu.be/f0REOnjdlQU?t=1190 I referenced above).  "Please let me know how you find the XXCoarse DMT..." will do.  My OCD fixation on flattening the back is surely due to many, and I mean many, online folks like Marc repeatedly saying "ya gotta flatten the back", with much melodrama and gusto.  If they were to tell me the world was flat, again with as much gusto, I may have to throw out my science textbooks. :)